# what is the meaning of "sent attrib have 0xf" in sftp debug log?

Tags: linux, sftp

what is the meaning of "sent attrib have 0xf" in sftp debug log? I thought it is file permission & attributes, but after changing the file permission, still get same result in sftp debug log, always return 0xf value. could not figure out what is exactly the meaning of 0xf?

Comment: https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable

Answer (score 0):

According to the source of
[sftp-server.c](https://searchcode.com/file/5455449/usr/src/cmd/ssh/sftp-server/sftp-server.c/),
this is a general debug message.

As far as I could understand the code,
its only meaning that some known values were retrieved from a previous call.